# How can I show element next to image when image is hovered?

Tags: html, css

I want to show a message when hovering on an image using CSS. I have used the following code :

**Code:**

```css
.message {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.xyz:hover .message {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <img class="xyz">
  <span class="message">Message</span>
</div>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this way

```
.xyz:hover + .message{
   visibility: visible;
}
```

```css
.message {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.xyz:hover+.message {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <img class="xyz" alt="xyz">
  <span class="message">Message</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Next sibling style**

**.xyz:hover + .message**

```html
<div class="abc">
  <img class="xyz">
  <span class="message">Message</span>
</div>

<style>
.message {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: #000;
  }
  
  .xyz {
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
  }
  
  .xyz:hover+.message {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
</style>
```